# Change a SELECT statement to a DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table are a lot of duplicate rows. I have a SELECT that provides the data I want to delete but how can I do this? Whatever I try I get an error.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (         
              SELECT 1
                FROM tablename t2
               WHERE t2.column = t.column
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                     )
```

Comment: change `select *` to `delete`...

Comment: P.S., if you have duplicates then you need to start learning about [unique and primary keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key).

Comment: yes i tryed this but it shows error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM norma' at line 2 btw. kollation is utf8mb4_bin

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change 'SELECT *' to 'DELETE'

```
DELETE 
FROM tablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (         
              SELECT 1
              FROM tablename t2
              WHERE t2.column = t.column
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
              )
```

Comment: yes i tryed this but it shows error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM norma' at line 2 btw. kollation is utf8mb4_bin